# Every "setter" method requires a "getter" method in Scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, setter, getter

Scala programmer should have known that this sort of writing :

```
class Person{
   var id  = 0 
}
var p = new Person 
p.id 
p.id = 2
```

equals to

```
class Person{
private var _id = 0 
def id = _id
def id_=(i: Int) = _id = i
}
val p = new Person 
p.id // be equal to invoke id method of class Person
p.id = 2   // be equal to p.id_=(2)
```

in effect. But if you comment the getter method `def id = _id` , `p.id = 2` will cause a compilation error, saying

```
error: value key is not a member of Person
```

Could anyone explain why ?

Comment: Your two definitions of `Person` are not exactly equivalent, because the second one will also generate private getter and setter methods for `_id`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is so because the specification says so.

See the [Scala Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), p. 86, §6.15 Assignments.

Note that nothing prevents you from:

- making the getter `private`
- making the getter return another type
- making the getter “uncallable”, e.g. like this: `def id(implicit no: Nothing)`

Comment: your answer make me happy :-)

Comment: I can't see how this section of the spec requires a getter in order for the setter to work.  Can you (or anyone else) explain?

Comment: “If `x` is a parameterless function defined in some template, and the same template contains a setter function `x_=` as member, then the assignment `x = e` is interpreted as the invocation `x_=(e)` of that setter function.” This requires `x` to be a parameterless function.

Comment: In fact, at least on 2.10.4, the getter cannot be private. The third trick (`implicit no: Nothing`) works, though.